# How to implement a type-bound write statement output in a Fortran derived-type or class

Tags: python, oop, fortran, derived-types

Suppose I have this simple class:

```
   Module Foo
        ...
        character(len=3), parameter :: describe_Foo=(/'BAR', 'BED', 'BOD'/)
        ...
        type :: A
            real :: value
            integer :: descriptor
        contains
            procedure :: getter
            procedure :: setter
            ...
        end type A

   contains
        function writetype(self,...)
            ...
            write(writetype,*) self%value, describe_foo(self%descriptor)
        end function writetype
   ...
   end module Foo
```

How can I define its interface to "write" so that every time this type is passed to the write statement it outputs the string defined by the class method `writetype`.

In other words, in Python parlance, can I implement the equivalent of an `__str__()` method?

I've found tantalizing tidbits suggesting that this is possible, see [User-defined derived-type Input/Output procedures (Fortran 2003)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/compbg/v121v141/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlf141.bg.doc/language_ref/uddtioprocedures.html)  and [User-defined derived-type Input/Output procedure interfaces (Fortran 2003)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/compbg/v121v141/topic/com.ibm.xlf141.bg.doc/language_ref/uddtioi.html). These documents give ample information to write the methods I need, but it is still unclear to me how to define an interface or procedure specification so that the behavior I want occurs.

Example application:

```
program test
    ...
    type(A) :: bartype, bedtype
    ...
    bartype=A(120.0,1)
    bedtype=A(102.0,2)
    write(*,*) bartype,bedtype
end program test
```

Desired output:

```
>test.exe
 120.0000 BAR
 102.0000 BED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a generic WRITE(FORMATTED) binding, bound to a specific procedure that has suitable characteristics.  See section 9.6.4.8 in the F2008 standard for more information.

```
type :: A
  real :: value
  integer :: descriptor
contains
  procedure :: writetype
  generic :: write(formatted) => writetype
end type A
...
subroutine writetype(dtv, unit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
  ! Argument names here from the std, but you can name them differently.
  class(A), intent(in) :: dtv         ! Object to write.
  integer, intent(in) :: unit         ! Internal unit to write to.
  character(*), intent(in) :: iotype  ! LISTDIRECTED or DTxxx
  integer, intent(in) :: v_list(:)    ! parameters from fmt spec.
  integer, intent(out) :: iostat      ! non zero on error, etc.
  character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg  ! define if iostat non zero.
  ...
  write (unit, "(F9.4,1X,A)", IOSTAT=iostat, IOMSG=iomsg)  &
      dtv%value, describe_foo(dtv%descriptor)
end subroutine writetype
```

It is probably also worth noting that you need a compiler that implements this!

Comment: Thank you, just what I was seeking!